# initial column width not respected

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've setup the initial column widths but they are not being respected if the width of all columns is less than the grid width.

I Played around with `fixed`, `forceFit`, and `autowidth` but nothing makes it work when the grid is rendered the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the option which you missed is `shrinkToFit: false`.